# How do I Add This to My Java Applet?

Tags: java, swing, applet

This is a simple class I would like to add to an applet, but how do I do it?

These are the variables being used:

```
int force = 1;
int distance = 50/force;
int x = distance*60;
int WIDTH = 300 - x;
```

This is the paint method:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g.drawString("Use the buttons to control the input force", 100, 25);
    g.fillRect(300, 250, 300, 25);
    g.fillRect(x, 250, WIDTH, 25);
```

If I should change what method these buttons are located in, please tell me. (Currently are in the paint method)

```
    JButton subtract = new JButton("-");
    JButton add = new JButton("+");
    add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                force++;
            }

        });

    subtract.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            force--;
            }
        });
    add.setSize(50, 25);
    subtract.setSize(50, 25);
    if(force<=0){
        force =1 ;
    }
    add.setLocation(0,0);
    subtract.setLocation(51, 0);
    LApplet app = new LApplet();
    app.add(add);
    app.add(subtract);
    app.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}}
```

Comment: As the @MadProgrammer will tell you, Applet is a deprecated technology.  So you should consider using something else.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).